# MySQL values to be in one column just separated by a comma

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a query that is pulling alot of data together and I would like it to only have one row vs x amount, and it just be one but the column Product ID, which is the last one, to just be all on one line, example data:

```
ID  FN      LN      MEM     REP     EMAIL                   PID
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     001
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     002
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     003
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     004
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     005
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     006
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     007
```

But would like the output to be:

```
001 Test    User    1001    1001    testemail@gmail.com     001,002,003,004,005,006,007
```

My SQL knowledge is not super strong so im kinda lost, any help would be awesome. I tried GROUP BY but some of the data as different values in the fourth column so it wont always work.

Comment: If this is a many-to-many relationship between users and products, my preference would be to use a junction table. You can find a diagram of what I mean at the bottom of [this](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) page. It will make your life easier down the road if you need to modify either users or products independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP_CONCAT` along with `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT ID, LN, EMAIL, GROUP_CONCAT(PID) as products
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

Or something like that.  `GROUP_CONCAT(productID)` will combine them into one row and `GROUP BY` tells it how to combine the rows together.

If you remove the `GROUP BY`, you will get one row with all the results found.  If you add it, it tells it how to combine the rows, which field to match.

Answer (score 2):

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is probably what you're looking for. So you can group and concatenate the Product ID and group it by a common attribute of your data records.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

It's the same thing as Stuff For XML in TSQL